# How to use Login View in django?

Tags: django, authentication

I decided to customize the login form and do authentication with email. I can login with a super user account but can't do it with the simple user.

Here's the `models.py` file. I created a custom user manager and redefined the creation logic:

````
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Staff must be True')

        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be True')

        if other_fields.get('is_active') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Is active must be True')
        
        return self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields)


    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('You must provide an email')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email = email, 
                            user_name = user_name, 
                            first_name=first_name, 
                            last_name = last_name, 
                            **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    head = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False,  blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False,  blank=True)

    dashmodel = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True) 

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name','first_name','last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name ```

I change the logic of login with email: 

``` UserModel = get_user_model()


class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(user_name__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_password(password)
            return
        except UserModel.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            user = UserModel.objects.filter(Q(user_name__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username)).order_by('id').first()

        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user```
````

And here's the login view:

```
class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login-test.html'
    success_url = '/dashboard/model-filter/'
    extra_context ={
        'title':'Login Form',
        'btn_label':'Login',
        'redirect_url':'register',
        'redirect_title':"Want to register?",
    }
```

If I'm trying to login with super user everything works perfect. But when I try to use a simple user I get the following error in the form:
"Please enter a correct email address and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

And one more noob question: how do I track the error of `LoginView` and all entered information in logs?

Answer (score 0):

For your non-super user is_active=False by default, and the default AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS reject inactive users.